# "Disk quota exceeded" error

Tags: nfs, disk-usage, quota

In our lab, NFS server has been setup. This server has home directories of all users. Quota is enabled for all users.

```
root@server:/users/labuser# du -sh
69M        .


root@lab-01:~# quota -su labuser
Disk quotas for user labuser (uid 52022):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit  grace
10.x.y.z:/users   301M*   196M    200M    none    1903       0       0
```

**'du -sh'** shows 69MB whereas **quota** shows 301M.
User is getting "disk quota exceeded" error. He is unable to create/save any file/directory.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

He has more files in some other directory, or your quota file has become out of sync.  If you can't find files he owns elsewhere, then rebuild the quota file with `quotacheck`.